# How to check difference between two date time fields

Tags: apex, datetime

I'm updating two date times using Workflow. I need to make a field null if the difference is less than 14 days. I'm not able to get correct results. My code is :

```
Integer firstdate = FieldA.getTime();
Integer seconddate = FieldB.getTime();
if((seconddate - firstdate)/(1000*24*60*60)<14) {
Field C = null;
```

Can anyone tell if this method is right

Comment: Looks fine to me. Can you provide a concrete example or two of when this code isn't producing the result you want? Also, knowing a bit more of the context in which this code is executed would be helpful. Is it in a Trigger? If so, what trigger event (or events) is it run in? If it's in an "after" trigger, do you actually update your record?

Comment: @DerekF They're coercing a 64-bit value into a 32-bit value. Hilarity ensues...

Answer (score 4):

getTime returns a Long, not an Integer. You'll get invalid results if you use Integer values, which will roll over every ~24 days. This means, for example, if your first date is at a 23 day boundary, and the second is at 26 days, you'll likely see something like a ~21 day difference instead of the 3 days you expected. Here's how you would change this:

```
Long firstdate = FieldA.getTime();
Long seconddate = FieldB.getTime();
if(secondDate - firstDate < 14L * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) {

}
```

Note that the `L` suffix is used to coerce 14 to a Long value, which will turn all subsequent numbers into Long values as well via automatic arithmetic promotion.